# error: conversion from 'Counter' to non-scalar type 'CountDn' in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
class Counter
{
protected:
unsigned int count;
public:
    Counter ():count ()
  { }
    Counter (int c):count (c)
  { }
  unsigned int get_count () const
  { return count;}
  Counter operator ++ ()
  {return Counter (++count);}
  };

  class CountDn:public Counter
  {
  public:CountDn ():Counter (){ }
  CountDn (int c):Counter (c){ }
  CountDn operator -- ()
  {return CountDn (--count);}
  };

  int main ()
  {
    CountDn c1;
    CountDn c2 (100);
    cout << "\nc1=" << c1.get_count ();
    cout << "\nc2=" << c2.get_count ();
    ++c1;
    ++c1;
    ++c1;
    cout << "\nc1=" << c1.get_count ();
    --c2;
    --c2;
    cout << "\n c2=" << c2.get_count ();
    CountDn c3 = ++c2;
    cout << "\n c3=" << c3.get_count ();
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting given error when I use overloaded '++' operator while it works out fine when I use '--'.

Error message is

```
37:14: error: conversion from ‘Counter’ to non-scalar type ‘CountDn’ requested
 CountDn c3 = ++c2;
```

Why do I obtain this error?
What does this error mean and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

> *I am getting given error when I use overloaded '++' operator while it works out fine when I use '--'.*

You have implementation of operator overloading of -- but not of ++ in CountDn class

You are missing operator overloading for ++ in CountDn class 
you will have to add

```
CountDn operator ++ ()
{return CountDn (++count);}
```

After modification

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Counter
{
protected:
    unsigned int count;
public:
    Counter ():count ()
    { }
    Counter (int c):count (c)
    { }
    unsigned int get_count () const
    { return count;}
    Counter operator ++ ()
    {return Counter (++count);}

};

class CountDn:public Counter
{
public:CountDn ():Counter (){ }
    CountDn (int c):Counter (c){ }
    CountDn operator -- ()
    {return CountDn (--count);}
    CountDn operator ++ ()
    {return CountDn (++count);}
};

int main ()
{
    CountDn c1;
    CountDn c2 (100);
    cout << "\nc1=" << c1.get_count ();
    cout << "\nc2=" << c2.get_count ();
    ++c1;
    ++c1;
    ++c1;
    cout << "\nc1=" << c1.get_count ();
    --c2;
    --c2;
    cout << "\n c2=" << c2.get_count ();
    CountDn c3 = ++c2;
    cout << "\n c3=" << c3.get_count ();
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
c1=0
c2=100
c1=3
 c2=98
 c3=99
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of

```
Counter operator ++ ()
    {return Counter (++count);}
```

is of the type `Counter` and there is no conversion from `Counter` to `CountDn`.
The following line compiles ok:

```
Counter c3 = ++c2;
```